# How to handle suggested edits that add code highlighting?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

In the *suggested edits* review queue I've recently (over a 3 day period) seen a single user make **30+** suggested edits where syntax highlighting is added to code samples with `<!-- language: php -->`

**All the questions** had the [laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel) tag and were missing the [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) tag.

In a single case the user made 4 suggested edits to a single question and it's 3 answers.

Normally I just add the [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) tag in such siturations (this adds automatic syntax highlighting to the question and all answers).

What is the correct practice here? Should I reject the edits (although they do improve the question/answer)? Or are those edits okay?

Comment: If a post has _only that specific edit_ and any other improvements are missing I would reject it and maybe try to improve it myself. And also mod flag a post requesting them to check out the behavior... 30 is quite a lot of edits to flood the review queue

Comment: @SurajRao I'm not the PHP person but I do find a lot of posts that have syntax highlighting problems, if you're going to suggest that course of action, how exactly am I supposed to notify high rep users that they should do this for me? I'd rather not eat a suggested edit reject just for the sake of bringing attention to a post. Leaving comments like "can somebody correct the syntax highlighting" almost never works. (if you're interested I can provide you a gist of posts that could use fixing)

Comment: @jrh when you make a change you need to look for all improvements the particular post needs... Mass adding tags/syntax highlighting while ignoring any other changes required to n number of posts clogs the review queue and wastes time.

Comment: @SurajRao In general I'm alright with that, as long as there's some consistency to what "completeness" means, e.g., some reviewers think that `backticks` aren't useful (and even worth rejecting), but some do. Do I add backticks (for completeness) or not (needless, annoying formatting)? Also, it wasn't your review but FWIW I can't find anything else that needed changing in [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15205486).